Word2Vec cannot read first line from pretrained model txt
Im trying to usa a pretrained w2vec model from a txt file.
Here is my code and error i get:
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

w2vec_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("/Users/trungtom/Downloads/W2V_150.txt", binary=False)


ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
The problem i think is "KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format" cannot read first line "77021 150" as two float but string.

Where did the file come from? Are you sure it's in the right format, and downloaded fully/completely? Can you edit your question to show the first 5 lines of the file (eg the results of head -5 W2V_150.txt from within that directory) and the full error traceback you're receiving, with all involved code-lines/etc? (That will help deduce where exactly in the reading the error is happening.)
